# how to use java util class (or static method) in camel route to modify Exchange properties

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to have CamelUtils class with the method setProperty

```
public final class CamelUtils {
    public static void setProperty(Exchange exchange, String name, Object value) {
        exchange.setProperty(name, value);
    }
}
```

I would like to use it in camel route like

```
<route>
   <from uri="direct:hello">
   <to uri="CamelUtils.setProperty(exhange, strName, strValue)"/>
   ... use property anyhow
</route>
```

How could I make it work?

---

I've found proper way of setting property in XML DSL:

```
<setProperty propertyName="propName"><simple>${body.someField}</simple></setProperty>
```

Comment: Use the bean component - read the Camel docs for more details

Answer (score 2):

The exchange is passed by default if no parameters used.
You can set two headers for the other parameters and use

```
 <from uri="direct:hello">
    <setHeader headerName="name">
                    <constant>name</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="value">
                    <constant>value</constant>
                </setHeader>
 <to uri="bean:mypackage.CamelUtils?method=setProperty"/>
```

and then in the method

```
public static void setProperty(Exchange exchange, @Header("name") String name, @Header("value") Objectvalue) {
        exchange.setProperty(name, value);
    }
```